# How to match the prefix of a number in php using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to check the prefix of a number. The following is my code;

```
   if (preg_match('[^\070|071|072|25470|25471|25472]', $phoneno)) {
                $countryCode="254";
                $newNumber = preg_replace('/^0?/', $countryCode, $phoneno);
                  } else {
                $response = array("status_code"=>"1234","message"=>"Invalid Phone number");
                $this->response(json_encode($response),200,$this->callback);
        }
```

Every time a request is made the response I get is "Invalid Phone number".

Comment: `|` is no more an OR when it is in a character class. Inside a character class characters have no order, writing `[070|074]` is the same than `[|047]` and matches only one character.

Comment: `/^0?/` matches all the strings of the world since the first and unique character is optional.

Comment: I guess you mean `preg_match('/^(070|071|072|25470|25471|25472)/', $phoneno)`, do you? This will find the numbers in alternation at the beginning of the string. What is the valid and invalid input?

Comment: Even shorter! preg_match('/^(254|0)(70|71|72)/', $phoneno);

Comment: @stribizhev That Still generates the same error

Comment: @KelvinMuli: *What is the valid and invalid input?*. Have a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/LmKpj3). BTW, in your regex, `[]` are regex delimiters, and `^` is only applied to the `070`, all other values are matched even inside the string. There is no character class, as some write in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$phonenos = [
    "25470666666",
    "25471666666",
    "25472666666",
    "070666666",
    "071666666",
    "072666666",
    "justtesting",
    "666666",
];

foreach($phonenos as $phoneno) {
    if (preg_match('/^(254|0)(70|71|72)/', $phoneno)) {
        $countryCode = "254";
        $newNumber = preg_replace('/^0/', $countryCode, $phoneno);
        print("matched<br>\n");
    } else {
        print("not matched<br>\n");
    }
}
```